# unable to retrieving table through lxml, xpath (unanswered)

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

I"m trying to scrape `http://www.sgx.com/wps/portal/sgxweb/home/company_disclosure/stockfacts` for this table, and return the `Company Name`, `Code` and `industry` into a list, for all 15 pages of it.

[image: Table I am trying to retrieve]

And i've been trying to work with `lxml.html`, `xpath` and `Beautifulsoup` to try and get this information, but i'm stuck.

I realised that this information seems to be a `#html` embedded within the website, but i'm not sure how I can build a module to retrieve it.

Any thoughts? Or if I should be using a different module/technique?

**Edit**

I found out that this link was embedded into the website, which consist of the `#html` that I was talking about previously: `http://sgx.wealthmsi.com/index.html#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sgx.com%2Fwps%2Fportal%2Fsgxweb%2Fhome%2Fcompany_disclosure%2Fstockfacts`

When I tried to use Beautifulsoup to pull the data out:

```
r = requests.get('http://sgx.wealthmsi.com/index.html#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sgx.com%2Fwps%2Fportal%2Fsgxweb%2Fhome%2Fcompany_disclosure%2Fstockfacts')
wb = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(wb.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'table-wrapper results-display'}))
```

It returns the result below:

```
[<div class="table-wrapper results-display">
<table>
<thead>
<tr></tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>]
```

But that's different from what is in the website. Any thoughts?

Comment: Anyone has any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to address this problem another way.

By looking at the server calls (chrome -> F12 -> network tab), you can figure out which url you should actually call to get a json response instead.
Apparently, you could use a url that starts like this:
http://sgx-api-lb-195267723.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/sgx/search?callback=json&json=???? (you'll need to do some reverse engineering to figure out the actual json query but it doesn't look too difficult)
Sorry I did not look much further into the json query but I hope this helps you keep going :)

Note: I based my answer on this [url](http://sgx-api-lb-195267723.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/sgx/search?callback=json&json=%7B%22criteria%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22marketCap%22%2C%22from%22%3A0.054000108000000005%2C%22to%22%3A70324.06611657784%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22totalRevenue%22%2C%22from%22%3A-36.897991%2C%22to%22%3A116163.990212%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22peRatio%22%2C%22from%22%3A0.003320631507861257%2C%22to%22%3A2475.4901960784314%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22dividendYield%22%2C%22from%22%3A0.22%2C%22to%22%3A7035.19%7D%5D%7D&_=1456391138953)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

url = "http://sgx-api-lb-195267723.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/sgx/search"

params = {
    'callback': 'json',
    'json': {
        # key / value pairs defining your actual query to the server
        # you need to figure this out yourself depending on the data you want
        # to retrieve.
        # I usually look at chrome's network tab (F12), find the proper URL
        # that queries for the data, reverse engineer the key/value pairs
    }
}

response = requests.get(url, params)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Any links from where I can learn about what you are doing? Very new to JSON and all.. :/

Comment: use the requests module pretty much as you did before but using a different URL to get your data in the json format, much easier to parse with python. I must admit the URL I pointed you at was not very accurate but I meant you could figure out the URL depending on the data you want to retrieve.
look at the requests package documentation for dealing with json here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content